# How to get eclipse to recognize preprocessor statements?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

I've managed to get the IDE to compile the java project correctly by modifying the config.ini, but the IDE itself is still showing errors concerning the processor statements:

```
//#ifdef VER_X
public class Video extends FirstCanvas {
//#else
public class Video extends SecondCanvas {
//#endif
...
```

Is there a setting or a plug-in that would solve this?

EDIT: Maybe a little clarification: I'm looking for something that will make the IDE editor more compliant with the code. It won't let me follow any definitions because of what the editor THINKS are errors.

Comment: Eclipse and Java don't have a preprocessor. Are you using a plugin like EclipseME?

Comment: This is interesting - I never knew that preprocessors were possible in Java.

Comment: They aren't. Only with help of some special IDE plugins

Comment: Having programmed in C++ for many years, I hope these stay far away from Java.  Those are one of the many ways C++ facilitates developers shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: I agree on a certain level. I use them for supporting multiple handheld OS's so I can have just one code base instead of 3 or 4 slightly different ones.

Comment: Alan, people abusing preprocessor directives is not a good reason to discourage their legitimate use.  Separating code designed for different device platforms, or API levels is exactly the kind of thing preprocessor directives should be used for.  Creating separate projects, or separate classes, to accomplish this same thing (both of which create dual maintenance) may be a poor substitute for preprocessor directives if the code differences are small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more OO approach to this would use separate classes, selecting between them at runtime:

```
public class FirstVideo extends FirstCanvas {
   ...
}

public class SecondVideo extends SecondCanvas {
   ...
}

...
video = (something ? new FirstVideo() : new SecondVideo());
```

This does not require non-standard compilation steps to achieve and doesn't open the door to the eldritch horrors of C/C++ preprocessor directives.

Comment: It doesn't always work with OO. Eg. I have made a library that must work with another library that can come (in the final user) in two incompatible versions. One version defines `void save()`, the next version defines it as `boolean save()`. No way to cleanly override these two definitions in the same source! Another usage is to define the same class to use primitives: it can be annoying to maintain the same code to support, eg. int, long, float and double. Another case is the shaped window code: in 1.6, it uses a Sun private API, in 1.7 it is more standard, you can't write code for both. Etc.

Comment: @PhiLho See the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Build your own common interface (or pick one of the existing alternatives) and build adapters for the other interfaces.

Answer (score 15):

Using a preprocessor is never necessary (nor advisable) in java.  It is far better to configure Subversion (or your favorite source manager) to pull in the correct version of various java files that are unique to each application and to reference platform neutral bridge classes (which extend the correct platform classes brought in via subversion) instead of referencing platform specific classes directly from global classes that are shared by multiple platforms.  However, sometimes the need for a java preprocessor is forced upon us due to its extensive use in pre-existing code that is being repurposed.  (For example, making a new Android version of an existing Blackberry application.)  If you find yourself in that situation, then here is how to use a preprocessor in your java code inside of Eclipse:

**Install the Antenna plug-in:**

Make sure that you have everything that you've been working on in Eclipse saved.

Go to "Help" in top menu in Eclipse and click on "Install New Software..." option.

Click on the "Add..." button.

Put "Antenna" in the "Name:" edit box and "http://antenna.sf.net/update" in the "Location:" edit box, then click on the "OK" button.

Expanded the "Uncategorized" plugin group,  check the checkbox for "Antenna eclipse plugins" (Version 1.1.8), then "click" on the Next button.

Click on the "Finish" button.

If a security warning pops up, then click on the "OK" button.

Make sure that you close any other instances of Eclipse that you have running, then click on the "Yes" button to restart this instance of Eclipse.

**Mark the project as processible by Antenna:**

Create the project, if needed.

Right click on the project.

Click on the "Antenna Preprocessor" option located about three quarters of the down on the pop-up menu, if it does not already have a check mark next to it.

Make sure the device.xml file used by Antenna is located in the correct folder.

**HERE IS AN EXAMPLE device.xml FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?> 

<devices>
 <device supportsPolishGui="true">
  <capability name="android" value="true" />
  <capability name="sqlite" value="true" />
  <identifier>Android</identifier> 
  <features>isVirtual</features> 
  <groups>XT</groups> 
  </device>
</devices>
```

For Android this is '"project"/resources' and for Blackberry this is '"project"/res'.
(Android only wants Android specific files in the "project"/res folder.)

**Set up Antenna for the project:**

Select the project by clicking on it.

Go to Project->Properties->Antenna Preprocessor.

If a warning pops up telling you that the device cannot be found, then click on the 'OK' button.

Click the 'Clear' button for 'Optional directory of device database.' combo box if it is not empty.  (This must be done even if the correct directory is already showing).

Click the 'Browse' button and select the folder where the device.xml is located. (For Android this is '"project"/resources' and for Blackberry this is '"project"/res'.)

Click the 'Clear' button for 'Device Name' combo box if it is not empty.  (This must be done even if the correct device is already showing.)

Click the 'Search' button and select the device. (For Android this is 'Android' and for Blackberry this is 'Black Berry'.)

Click the 'OK' button.

Antenna will now go thru all of the files in the project and comment ('// @') or uncomment code enclosed by preprocessor commands (must start with '//#') depending upon the settings in the device.xml file.

**NOTE:** This may cause the java files in the global packages to be marked as out of sync with Subversion.  This can cause issues for Subversion if someone else uploads their changes and then you get the changes from head via Subversion.  If global java files are marked as out of sync with Subversion due to Antenna, then it is usually best to commit those changes immediately for any of those files that you plan on changing later.

**Using Antenna after initial setup for the project:**
Anytime a file in the project is changed and saved after this Antenna will comment ('// @') or uncomment code enclosed by preprocessor commands (must start with '//#') depending upon the settings in the device.xml file as part of the saving process.

**NOTE:** The //#preprocess statement at the first line in java files that Blackberry preprocessed will have to be removed since Antenna will have to be used for all java files instead of the Blackberry preprocessor.

**NOTE:** If the device.xml file is changed, then you will have to set up Antenna for each project that uses the device.xml as described above again for the changes to take effect.

**Preprocessor commands and options used by Antenna are explained here:**
http://antenna.sourceforge.net/wtkpreprocess.php

Comment: +1... Wish I could Vote more than once for your Answer. Really detailed explanation. Only thing is replace the 'device.xml' with 'custom-devices.xml', then it should work without a glitch.... Thanks a lot man...

Comment: Great examples but how can you change quickly the setup for antenna, I mean using a custom config or another ? I couldn't find any way to fast switch, the only thing I can do is defining a single new value

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, precompiler directives could be quite useful from a Security standpoint. It's never a good idea to leave debug code in product that goes to release. This is because anyone can start inspecting memory and changing things, and suddenly the inner workings of your code are there for an attacker to inspect. But removing debug code makes finding problems down the road considerably more difficult. Being able to #ifdef out debug code so that it is never put into the release jar would be extremely useful.

That being said, no you can'd do this in Java.

Charles.