# How do I get current date in the android manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

How do I get current date in the android manifest file?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.ihavenocompany.istillhaveprojects.customer.android"
      android:versionCode="23"
      android:versionName="0.9.9.9-2013.09.19-devo">
```

How can i obtain the current date so that i dont have to change the versionName everytime i commit.

...Without going in the discussion of should we have a date in the versionName.

Boils down to how to update the manifest file on build

Comment: Are you asking: "how to change the buildprocess to automaticcally include compile-date into android manifest?" Updateing the question title may be helpful

Comment: Either ways is fine...I want it to be automatically updated

Answer (score 1):

> How can i obtain the current date so that i dont have to change the
>   versionName everytime i commit.

=> You can't change versionName programatically but yes you can retrieve versionCode or versionName.

> should we have a date in the versionName.

=> Yes you can put anything as it takes String values. As I said above, you can't change it programatically.

Comment: im looking to edit this at build time. Is it possible to invoke custom classes and set this value? I am ok with writing a class which gives the current date and using it here. Are variables allowed in this file?

Answer (score -1):

You can not edit your manifest at runtime, as it is static, but you can always use C style preprocessor commands. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586204/783707

I leave the logic upto you :)

Comment: im looking to edit this at build time. Is it possible to invoke custom classes and set this value? I am ok with writing a class which gives the current date and using it here. Are variables allowed in this file?

Comment: Dude, am not gonna spoon-feed you. Read the attached link first